# Does the GaussianDropout Layer in Keras retain probability like the Dropout Layer?

Tags: keras, gaussian

I was wondering, if the GaussianDropout Layer in Keras retains probability like the Dropout Layer.
The Dropout Layer is implemented as an Inverted Dropout which retains probability.

If you aren't aware of the problem you may have a look at the [discussion](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3305) and specifically at the linxihui's answer.
The crucial point which makes the Dropout Layer retaining the probability is the call of K.dropout, which isn't called by a GaussianDropout Layer.

Is there any reason why GaussianDropout Layer does not retain probability?
Or is it retaining but in another way being unseen?

Similar - referring to the Dropout Layer: [Is the Keras implementation of dropout correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592943/is-the-keras-implementation-of-dropout-correct)

Comment: here the differences between GausDropout Dropout and GausNoise https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504785/10375049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Gaussian dropout doesn't need to retain probability as its origin comes from applying *Central Limit Theorem* to inverted dropout. The details might be found [here](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf) in 2nd and 3rd paragraph of Multiplicative Gaussian Noise chapter (chapter 10, p. 1951).

Comment: Is there anything more you want to know? You haven't upvoted my answer.

Comment: Atm I am satisfied. But I accepted your answer. 
Better? ;D

Comment: Cool :) I thought thay you weren't fully satisfied.

Comment: I don't understand the theory entirely, but I guess it doesn't matter. 
The most important information (to me) is: 
I can use GaussianDropout layer in Keras with a clear conscience!