# What is the proper way to implement an inverse dropout layer in keras?

Tags: python, keras, sequential, dropout

I read a lot of math explanations on this here which I understood nothing. Can anyone provide a simple code example?

I am looking for a keras sequential model example.

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Keras already has an implementation of Dropout, what's the problem with using it?

Comment: I was asking about inverse dropout. I couldn't find anything.

Comment: What I mean is that Keras already implements inverted Dropout. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592943/is-the-keras-implementation-of-dropout-correct

Comment: I have seen that one, what I understand is that you have to manually reshape the output at every layer? I thought there could be a function as simple as "model.add(InverseDropout(x,y)". I am not sure how to use it with sequential model.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, there is no reshaping needed, inverted dropout is already the default implementation of Dropout, you just need to do model.add(Dropout(0.5))

Comment: #encoder layers:
dense()
dropout(.5)
conv2d

#decoder layers:
deconv2d
dropout(.5)
dense()

should be like this?

Comment: You didn't mention that you were implementing an autoencoder, so you are trying to find an actual inverse to what Dropout does. There is no inverse and you don't actually need one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187530/discussion-between-leon-rai-and-matias-valdenegro).